# How to plot a range of data with time in hh:mm:ss.000 format in R?

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a set of data that need to be plotted (1M rows) with **R**. The time column (column 1) is in hh:mm:ss.000 format. I would like to plot the graph in a time range, say from 08:05:00 to 09:00:00. How do I do it? I have searched the web and couldn't find a way to set the xlim properly.

Here's a short example of the data. Column 1 is time, Column 2, 3, 4.. will be on y axis.

```
07:51:19.553,10.785,0.000,0.392,1.512,1.527,1.553,1.560,2.838

08:05:00.661,-1.555,0.000,0.041,0.310,0.314,0.321,0.327,1.474

08:06:58.250,30.781,0.000,0.093,0.156,0.160,0.168,0.173,1.411

08:30:02.506,-0.002,0.000,0.052,0.120,0.123,0.132,0.137,1.361

09:05:00.997,-1.802,0.000,0.032,0.078,0.080,0.087,0.090,1.258

10:05:00.661,-1.555,0.000,0.041,0.310,0.314,0.321,0.327,1.474
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You *really* want to use a proper time series class such as [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) or [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts)

Subsetting, plotting, ... then come for free.  Start with the excellent [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) documentation before maybe switching to [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) for even better performance and subsetting.

Now, one million rows is too many as you end up with more data than pixels -- but at least this will give you a chance to summarize your data.

Here is a quick illustration:

```
> options(digits.sec=3)      ## important: turn on milli-sec via print()
> library(xts)
Loading required package: zoo
> X <- xts(cumsum(rnorm(100)), order.by=Sys.time()+cumsum(runif(100)/10))
> plot(X)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Bear with me. I am a newby in R.
> library(xts)
Error in library(xts) : there is no package called 'xts'
Do I need something else? I have R version 2.11.1 (2010-05-31)

Comment: Ah, yes:  Do `install.packages(c("zoo", "xts"))` and select a nearby mirror.

Comment: It looks like I have trouble accessing the index for repository. Not sure if my company blocks the access or not. Maybe I will try it from home. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To change character vector to "date & time" object, POSIXlt(ct) object, function `strptime()` will come handy. Here's a short example how it's done.

```
dtm <-  strptime(c("1.1.2010 11:35"), format =  "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M", tz = "CET")
```

Comment: I have no problem display the string in hh:mm:ss.000. Trouble is on limit time range in ploting